# How to get Data/view statistics of a page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering, how can I get statistics like these in Rails ?

1. How many unique views a page like /page/1, /page/2 have got
2. From which countries they come from ?

as I want to display this info under those pages, I don't want to use any external library, I am hoping we can have some ruby gem which can do this

Thanks

EDIT 1 - I can see 1-2 gems like https://github.com/jkrall/analytical but still thought to ask the SO community

EDIT 2 - I don't think that above gem is what I am looking for it looks that it just insert 3rd party analytics into existing app

Answer (score 6):

Add the [Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) gem to your Gemfile and `bundle install`.

Create a `Visit` model with attributes `page`, `ip_address` and `location`.

For the pages in question, put a before filter in the relevant controllers or if you want to record visits to every page put it in your ApplicationController:

```
def record_visit
  Visit.create(page: request.fullpath, ip_address: request.ip, location: request.location.country_code)
end
```

The Geocoder gem adds the `location` method to the request object so read up on the docs if you need more than the country code.

You can then display the number of views on a particular page by inserting the following into your controller, again in a before_filter but this must run after the previous filter:

```
def count_views
  @views = Visit.where(page: request.fullpath).count
end
```

As you'll be running this query a lot, you'll probably want to put an index on the page attribute when creating your Visit model.

```
add_index :visits, :page
```

Unique views is tricky because you can of course have multiple visitors from the same IP address. You could set a cookie as part of the `record_visit` method and then not create a new visit if the cookie exists.

```
def record_visit
  if cookies['app-name-visited']
    return
  else
    cookies['app-name-visited'] = true
    Visit.create(page: request.fullpath, ip_address: request.ip, location: request.location.country_code)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Robin, ok lets take it step by step. I just want "How many people viewed the page" (uniqueness doesn't matter), how can I do this ? is there any simple code/gem for this which give me any method whose result i can display ? Thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer. Everything up to the part about unique views is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, just wondering, what is your opinion about this gem https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist ?

Comment: I think it depends on how much detail you need/want. Looks good but records a lot of information for simple view counting.