# Disable Cookies on initial page load until user agrees to use them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, session-cookies

I am using this answer here to log unique page views in my app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174466/1235816

I am using a cookie to check for unique visits. As far as I am aware, because the site will be hosted in the UK, I should have a message which asks the user to accept cookies or if they don't... it asks them to leave the site.

I want it to work like this... If a user wishes to accept cookies, then the 'app-name-visited' cookie should then be downloaded, otherwise if they just exit the site without clicking accept, no cookies are downloaded to the clients machine...

Is this:
1/. a correct way of thinking?
2/. possible?

Comment: Isn't that law [dead](http://blog.silktide.com/2013/01/the-stupid-cookie-law-is-dead-at-last/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie law has since been modified, so this is not quite necessary any more, you only need to let the user know that they you will be using cookies.

The organisation that enforces this is the ico, which doesn't ask for permission for cookies on their site:

http://www.ico.org.uk/

Suggest you follow this pragmatic approach.

If you are wanting to comply as per your question I did some work on this a while back for rails projects which should be a decent starting point:
https://github.com/yule/threepwood